# Can't write to a C++ object from QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a program that displays images and can put different filters on these images. In the QML GUI I have a series of buttons that let you set which highlights are enabled.

```
Column{
    id: highlightButtons
    anchors {left: frameViewer.right; top: parent.top; leftMargin: 10; topMargin: 10 }
    spacing: 20
    Rectangle{
        id: class1
        color: "red"
        height: 45
        width: 45
        radius: 12
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {hl.red = frames[frameList.currentIndex];
                        loadImages(); console.log(hl.red)}
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: class2
        color: "green"
        height: 45
        width: 45
        radius: 12
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {hl.green = frames[frameList.currentIndex];
                        loadImages(); console.log(hl.green)}
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: class3
        color: "blue"
        height: 45
        width: 45
        radius: 12
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {hl.blue = frames[frameList.currentIndex];
                        loadImages(); console.log(hl.blue)}
        }
    }
}
```

Where `frames` is a list of strings.

`hl` is a class that I use to store which highlights are enabled.

```
class HighlightModel : public QObject
{
    Q_PROPERTY(QString red READ getRed WRITE setRed NOTIFY redChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString blue READ getGreen WRITE setBlue NOTIFY blueChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString green READ getBlue WRITE setGreen NOTIFY greenChanged)
public:
    void setRed(QString &frame)
    {
        if(redHighlights.find(frame) != redHighlights.end())
        {
            redHighlights[frame] = !redHighlights[frame];
        }
        else
        {
            redHighlights.insert(std::pair<QString, bool>(frame, true));
        }
        emit redChanged();
    }

    void setGreen(QString &frame)
    {
        if(greenHighlights.find(frame) != greenHighlights.end())
        {
            greenHighlights[frame] = !greenHighlights[frame];
        }
        else
        {
            greenHighlights.insert(std::pair<QString, bool>(frame, true));
        }
        emit greenChanged();
    }

    void setBlue(QString &frame)
    {
        if(blueHighlights.find(frame) != blueHighlights.end())
        {
            blueHighlights[frame] = !blueHighlights[frame];
        }
        else
        {
            blueHighlights.insert(std::pair<QString, bool>(frame, true));
        }
        emit blueChanged();
    }

    bool getRed(QString frame)
    {
        return redHighlights[frame];
    }
    bool getGreen(QString frame)
    {
        return greenHighlights[frame];
    }
    bool getBlue(QString frame)
    {
        return blueHighlights[frame];
    }

    std::map<QString, bool> redHighlights;
    std::map<QString, bool> greenHighlights;
    std::map<QString, bool> blueHighlights;
signals:
    void redChanged();
    void greenChanged();
    void blueChanged();

private:


};
```

My understand of `Q_PROPERTY` is that setting `WRITE` to `setRed`, `setBlue` etc. should mean that when I set `hl.red` to something, it should call the function I associate with `WRITE`. However, I have put breakpoints in the code there and that code is never run. When I use `console.log` to print `hl.blue` it just prints the string that I tried to pass before. Can anyone clear this up for me? Have I misinterpreted how this works?

### EDIT

Here is the code where I associate the `HighlightModel` with the `engine`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << VERSION_INFO;
    FrameViewerWindow engine;
    InfoHolder ver;
    HighlightModel highlights;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ver", &ver);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("hl", &highlights);
    engine.addImageProvider("images", new ImageLoader(QQuickImageProvider::Image, &highlights));
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you did not declare `red`, `green` and `blue` QString members. Declare them inside the class and declare their getter(s)/setter(s) as `Q_INVOKABLE`.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih they do not have to exist, as long as getters (and setters and signals exist, when specified in the macro). However, the getters are not supposed to take arguments when used in `Q_PROPERTY`.

Comment: @anderas well, my way worked for me!

Comment: Try not to use breakpoint in the C++ but print something there with `std::cout` - probably your debugger wont attach to QML thread.

Comment: I used Marko's method and it seems to have worked although I still dont fully understand why my original code wasn't working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have two options, or call setContextProperties when you change data from the objects, or you register the Object for instanciate in Qml and get their reference in C++ (via property name) for change their data in Qml and C++(you will declar their methods like Q_INVOCABLE).